# Django and service workers - serve "sw.js" at application's root url

Tags: django, django-urls, django-staticfiles, service-worker

So I'm building a Django progressive web app with offline support using service workers.

According to [google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-offline-web-app/step-5?hl=en), the sw.js file should be at the root of the app's url:

> You need to do this because the scope of a service worker (the set of
>   urls that the ServiceWorker will load for) is defined by the directory
>   where it resides.

At the moment, I'm serving all static assets from http://example.com/static/ folder. But I need to serve this specific file at a url like: http://example.com/sw.js.

Any idea how I can achieve this? I could make a specific nginx rule to do this redirection, but I don't know if it's the cleanest way of doing this. Maybe this setting should reside in urls.py?

**Note**: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232922/django-staticfiles-at-url-root) which suggests using the static() method from `django.conf.urls.static`. But [django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/) say that the static method is only for development use so not good for me.

**Note (2)**: I guess I could change the `STATIC_URL` setting, but I'm happy with my files being served from /static directory. I only want this one file to be at url's root.

Answer (score 24):

You can serve javascript as a view, not just html. Put this in your projects urls.py

```
url(r'^service-worker.js', cache_control(max_age=2592000)(TemplateView.as_view(
    template_name="service-worker.js",
    content_type='application/javascript',
)), name='service-worker.js'),
```

Then put your `service-worker.js` in your templates directory.

Bonus is that you can now also use template tags like static in your javascript file.

Comment: You might want to remove the cache_control, as by default service workers can't be cached for more than 24 hours and usually you want to serve a new service worker as soon as it is available.

Comment: but I want varnish on the frontend to cache that page. Especially since it's going to be requested by every client, every 24 hours. Then you just cache bust the url, i.e. `var sw = navigator.serviceWorker.register('{% url 'service-worker.js' %}?v=13');`

Comment: Interesting. Does this have any downside if we're using WhiteNoise? won't it be cached until next deploy? (no ngnix available)

Answer (score 5):

Django 2.2

project structure

```
myproj/
|-app/
| |-templates/
|   |-app/
|     -sw.js
|-myproj/
  -urls.py
```

**urls.py (project)**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
  ...
  path('sw.js', (TemplateView.as_view(template_name="app/sw.js", 
  content_type='application/javascript', )), name='sw.js'),
]
```

Answer (score 4):

In Django 1.11 urls.py should look:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^sw.js', (TemplateView.as_view(template_name="sw.js", content_type='application/javascript', )), name='sw.js'),
]
```

Comment: why are you importing `cache_control`? top answer above works for all django urls

Answer (score 3):

I was getting all the time the error `DOMException: The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed`.

I spent hours trying to figure out the solution.

Apart from adding at `urls.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
  ...,
  url(r'^service-worker.js', (TemplateView.as_view(template_name="service-worker.js", content_type='application/javascript', )), name='service-worker.js'),
]
```

There was also another step needed.
Instead of

```
<script>
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log("Will the service worker register?");
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
      .then(function(reg){
        console.log("Yes, it did.");
     }).catch(function(err) {
       console.log("No it didn't. This happened:", err)
        console.log("err.message:", err.message)
    });
 }
</script>
```

I used:

```
<script>
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log("Will the service worker register?");
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("{% url 'service-worker.js' %}") //note that I am using the url template here
      .then(function(reg){
        console.log("Yes, it did.");
     }).catch(function(err) {
       console.log("No it didn't. This happened:", err)
        console.log("err.message:", err.message)
    });
 }
</script>
```