# django collectstatic with template processor

Tags: django

Is it possible to use templates for static files? I would like django could process the static files with template processor before copying them in the static folder when `manage collectstatic` is issued.

Of course the context would not contain request information but it could be useful to use such information as:

- urls from url names to be used in javascript code
- settings to be used to customize css or static html pages

What is the simpler way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

At least in the case of JavaScript I have previously done it. Please see the reference for calling a JavaScript service worker in the following link:

[Django and service workers - serve "sw.js" at application's root url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696595/django-and-service-workers-serve-sw-js-at-applications-root-url/47660210#47660210)

As far as the knowledge if it is a good design architecture I would not know. But may seem and interestingly enough idea to give it a try.