# Register Service Worker in Django

Tags: django, service-worker

I am trying to register service worker in django but I get this error

> DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script resource
>   is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.

My project structure is

```
src/
   templates/sw.js
   static/js/main.js  #file where I register service worker
```

main.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('sw.js', {scope: '/'})
            .then(function(reg) {
                console.log('Achieng Service worker Registration worked!');
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

    }
```

According to this [django-service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696595/django-and-service-workers-serve-sw-js-at-applications-root-url/40087795#40087795), I have defined my urls as

`path('sw.js/', (TemplateView.as_view(template_name="sw.js", content_type='application/javascript', )), name='sw.js'),`

and have my sw.js in templates folder.

What could I be missing? I want service worker to have a default scope '/'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your service worker is served at `/sw.js/`. Django automatically redirects `/sw.js` to `/sw.js/`. To make it work you simply have to remove the trailing slash in `path()`.

The convention in Django is to use a trailing slash in every url, but cases like this are an exception.

Comment: your answer is  helpful,unfortunately I can't  accept it because my  reputation.Thanks

Comment: @CindyAchieng You're welcome. You can't upvote, but you should be able to accept it (the checkmark next to the answer).