# Django Webmanifest

Tags: python, django, manifest

I'm building a PWA in Django.
The serviceworker is located in

```
pwa->static->pwa->sw.js
```

Everthing gets loaded/cached and the serviceworker is running.
If in manifest.json `"start_url": "/"` or `"start_url": "/pwa"` is set, i get this serviceworker not found error, from the manifest, so it's not installable, but if I set it to `"start_url": "."` i can install my App but then I get:

```
Directory indexes are not allowed here.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/pwa/
```

At app startup.
How can i overwrite or redirect this request to
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/pwa/` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Django and service workers - serve "sw.js" at application's root url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696595/django-and-service-workers-serve-sw-js-at-applications-root-url/40087795#40087795)

The last entry solves my question.

Manifest, sw.js and index.html now in the template folder.
The assets in static.

Linking in sw.js

```
var filesToCache = ["/pwa", "/static/pwa/vue.js",...
```